# (base) Admin's-iMac:~ admin$ , what is this (base)? After conda install

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I installed anaconda2 on my iMac. Then I use anaconda2 to install tensorflow.

Either by using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Or by using Anaconda Navigator, search the package tensorflow and then select to install.

In both cases, after I did the tensorflow installation. my command line terminal changed to

(base) Admin's-iMac:~ admin$ , (base) showed up now. What is this (base)?

In my .bash_profile,

```
# added by Anaconda2 2018.12 installer
    # >>> conda init >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/admin/anaconda2/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        \eval "$__conda_setup"
    else
        if [ -f "/Users/admin/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
            . "/Users/admin/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
            CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
        else
            \export PATH="/Users/admin/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
    unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda init <<<
```

I have these lines.

So it seems some of the conda setup conditions met, and

```
CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
```

So my login terminal will "conda activate base", using conda virtualenv.

So now my terminal showed (base) each time I opened the terminal window. Does it mean some errors happened with my conda or conda packages installation?

To get rid of the (base), I need to reinstall anaconda2.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `base` is the name of the virtualenv.

Comment: Yeah, the question is why every time I open the terminal, my terminal is using conda's virtualenv now? something is wrong with my conda or its packages, make my terminal using conda's virtualenv as default now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty late but anyway - I got the same using miniconda on wsl, windows.
You can turn it off by - `$conda deactivate` and the terminal comes back to normal.